# CSS - remove vertical spacing

Tags: css

I have a web page located at this URL http://www.hollox.net.

This is a simple page to test for a customer that need a specific menu containing pictures overlapping.

The positioning is relative.

I have two series of 3 pictures that are overlapping:

[image]
[image]

Is there a CSS tag that will remove space between the two series of div containers or do I have to manipulate the top property?

[image: white space]

Here the source code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test pour Patrick</title>
        <style type="text/css">

            .container
            {
                width: 800px;
                height: 400px;
                border: solid 5px yellow;
                text-align: center;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .table
            {
                position:relative;
                display: inline-table;
                width: 310px;
            }

            .row
            {
                position:relative;
                display: table-row;
            }

            .cell
            {
                position:relative;
                width: 100px;
                height: 100px;
                border: solid 1px black;
                display: table-cell;
            }

            .p
            {
                background-color: Gray;
                position:relative;
                float: left;
                clear: none;
                z-index: 1;
            }

            .x
            {
                background-color: Blue;
                position:relative;
                float: left;
                clear: none;
                z-index: 2;
                /* 100px x 3 = 300px */
                /* hardcoded value */
                top: -80px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="table">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell p"><img src="./images/p.png" /></div>
                    <div class="cell p"><img src="./images/p.png" /></div>
                    <div class="cell p"><img src="./images/p.png" /></div>
                    <div class="cell x"><img src="./images/x.png" /></div>
                    <div class="cell x"><img src="./images/x.png" /></div>
                    <div class="cell x"><img src="./images/x.png" /></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell p">A<img src="./images/p.png" /></div>
                    <div class="cell p">B<img src="./images/p.png" /></div>
                    <div class="cell p">C<img src="./images/p.png" /></div>
                    <div class="cell x">1<img src="./images/x.png" /></div>
                    <div class="cell x">2<img src="./images/x.png" /></div>
                    <div class="cell x">3<img src="./images/x.png" /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank you,
Have a great day!
Sébastien

Comment: please [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) your code

Comment: Thank you to make me discovered fiddle. Here my "fiddle" code: http://jsfiddle.net/Vbscc/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit `x` class like this:

```
.x {
background-color: #00F;
position: relative;
float: left;
clear: none;
z-index: 2;
margin-top: -80px;
```

use `margin-top: -80px;` instead `top:-80px;`

Comment: This work perfectly. I just read the difference between Top vs Margin-top. A new discovery! Thank you again!